# compiling and running through a command line

Tags: java, command-line, compilation, command-prompt

I have a general question.
I have been programming using Integrated development environment, for short (IDE). 
But I was watching a course in YouTube on Data Structure. The Lecturer said to his students that each one must know how to compile and run through a command a line.
The question is:
Why should programmers must know how to do that ? 
Thank you.

Comment: One of reasons is to truly understand what blessing IDE is.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite subjective, but some advantages of knowing how to compile your programs from the command line might be:

- You understand better what are the minimal tools you need to compile a program
- You understand better what it really means to compile a Java program. The IDEs usually compile each file as you modify it and hide lots of dependency issues from you.
- You learn about the CLASSPATH and all its implications. Again, many IDEs will hide/simplify this from you.
- You better identify all dependencies your program has. Many IDEs include libraries such as JUnit by default and you don't even know how to download them or reference them yourself.
- Usually production or continuous integration servers don't have IDEs installed. Understanding how to compile from the command line would allow you to troubleshoot complex issues in those servers.